# Read file from disk in java

Tags: java

I had an interview and they asked me to write a java code to read a file from a DISK. I know that I can use both `FileInputStream` and `BufferedReaders`.
But what is the most suitable and what is the reason ? Is there something special when we read from a disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs state one  usecase for [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html):

> FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as
>   image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using
>   FileReader.

So for Readers, the opposite apply.

A `FileInputStream` is reading `byte` by `byte`, while the [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) is reading `char` by `char`.

So if you're reading something with chars, use a Reader. If you're reading binary data, use a Stream.

Answer (score -1):

Using a [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is a good option for reading files. You can construct a Scanner object using a [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html), an [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) or a [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) object. In addition, a Scanner provides you with several built-in functions which can read most primitive types directly from the source.

Here is an example code for the usage of a Scanner to read long values from a file:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myNumbers.txt"));
   while (sc.hasNextLong()) {
      long aLong = sc.nextLong();
   }
```

The discussion here may be a helpful resource for you: [Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java)

I also find this resource helpful for my studies: [Ways of reading text file in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-reading-text-file-java/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not related to this is question in any way :/

Comment: Why do you suggest it is not related? I wanted to propose an alternative way to streams and readers. Scanner class is very simple and useful way while you are reading a file. Actually when I first come across to Scanner class was again an answer to a question which discusses barely InputStreams. So, I don't think that it is unrelated to topic.